# Bipartite Matching in the Plane

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, bipartite-matching, matching

I'm currently working on a problem that I came across:

> You are given a set $B$ of $n$ points in the plane, and a set $R$ of $n$ points in the plane. Each point is given by its coordinates. I have to Suggest an $O(n^{3})$ time algorithm for determining if there is a perfect matching between them, with the constraint that each point in $R$ is matched to a point in $B$ point whose distance is at most 1 unit away.

I have tried solving using the minimum distance using bipartite algorithm but could not arrive at a solution. Can anyone provide me with any ideas?

Comment: Are you allowed to use existing algorithms? There's a simple solution in that case.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the hungarian algorithm

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Why is this question put on hold by a moderator? I think it is clear what the OP was asking for, furthermore the OP said what he had tried.

Comment: see here for a fast algorithm for your problem http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86906/complexity-of-matching-red-and-blue-points-in-the-plane

Comment: @A.Schulz (You have to @-notify if you expect a reply.) It's true that the question includes a sentence of the form "I have tried..."; I just could not make enough sense of it to say that it's a "valid" attempt. Apparently, enough fellow users thought otherwise and reopened the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been solved by Alon Efrat, Alon Itai and Matthew J. Katz in their paper [Geometry Helps in Bottleneck Matching and Related Problems](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~alon/papers/match.pdf). The running time of the algorithm is $O(n^{1.5} \log n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using existing algorithms, you solve this with a basic network flow approach.

First construct a bipartite graph from the point sets where every point is a vertex in the graph and there is an edge between points $x$ and $y$ if $x\in R$, $y \in B$ and $d(x,y) \leq 1$. This takes $\mathcal{O}(n^{2})$ time.

Then we can apply the normal bipartite perfect matching algorithm, which uses a *Maximum Flow* approach:

- Add a source vertex $s$ and sink vertex $t$.
- Add all edges $su$ where $u \in R$.
- Add all edges $vt$ where $v \in B$
- Assign all edges a capacity of $1$ unit.

Then we have a flow network which has a flow of $n$ units if and only if there's a perfect matching between $R$ and $B$. Thus we can use any Max Flow algorithm we care to, but in particular the augmenting path algorithm, in this case, runs in time $\mathcal{O}(|V|\cdot|E|)$, which is at most $\mathcal{O}(n^{3})$.

Of course we can use any faster algorithm, and still answer the question positively.

Answer (score 1):

In time $O(n^2)$, you can construct a bipartite graph that has an edge from $r\in R$ to $b\in B$ if, and only if, they're at distance at most $1$ from each other. Then, use any standard algorithm for matchings of bipartite graphs: even the simplest ones run in time $O(n^3)$.